# This do/while loop repeat for no reason, how to fix it?

Tags: java, loops, error-handling, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to do a false credit card generator. So basically the problem is that when the user says "No" the program continues and shows "Goodbye" but then it starts all over again and can't find why.

I thought of putting all this do/while loop in a for loop so i can put a break at the end but it led to a dead code (which is logical).

```
public void generateCode() {
    char userAnswer;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Put a bin.");            
        String binGiven = sc.nextLine();

        verificationBin(); 
        showCardNumber();

        do {

            System.out.println("Do u wanna try again ? (Yes/No)");
            userAnswer = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);

        } while (userAnswer != 'Y' && userAnswer != 'N');

    } while (userAnswer == 'Y');

    System.out.println("Goodbye");
    sc.close();

}
```

I expected it to stop when the user says No but it starts all over again

Comment: How are you calling "generateCode" ?

Comment: Sorry my english is bad and iam new at programming but what do you mean by calling ? Here i'm just creating this method that i call generateCode().

Comment: he means could the flaw be not in the generateCode method but rather in the way it is called.

Comment: If the method reaches the point where it prints "Goodbye", then the problem is elsewhere, either in the direct caller or somewhere further down the call stack..

Comment: No I think i'm calling it right (the object is called generator so when I call the method I put "generator.generateCode();"

Comment: By the way, in the original code, it did terminate properly if you typed in 'N'. However, it did NOT work if you typed in 'n', "no", "No", or other variants as such.

Comment: Okay gonna check

Comment: Would you mind adding the rest of the code you use to call "generator.generateCode();" ? It could help troubleshooting. And as you are new to programming, debugging is your friend :)

Comment: The issue is not that you are invoking the method wrongly.  It is that you are invoking it *repeatedly*.

Comment: Here you go, you can see how i called the method and also the constructor. https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/32/2/1565112261-programmation.png

Comment: Made a [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CelebratedPastelOpensoundsystem) to demonstrate. In fact, it even accepted 'No' - it just matters if the first character is an uppercase 'N'

Comment: yes it only takes the first letter so here isn't the problem (i put N not n when the problem appears)

Comment: The code is a little bit different. I see you have a "for" in the image. We can't help you if your current code has a different logic.

Comment: Nexevis observation is correct. You should remove that "this.genererCode();" from Generateur's constructor

Comment: Okaaay @Nexevis that's it. I thought that if I wanted to use a method i have to put it in the constructor either way it won't work. I just deleted it and it now worked. Thanks !

Comment: Do I have to close the topic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to image you added you are calling the looping code twice.  Once from your constructor and once from your `main`.

This is your code currently:

```
Generator gen = new Generator();
gen.generateCode();
```

However, your constructor *inside* the `generator` class contains a call to the *same* method `generateCode()` shown here:

```
this.generateCode();
```

When you use `new Generator()` this runs the code inside of the constructor as well, so you are running the same code twice.  You can confirm this by attempting to run through the program two times and it should stop executing after the second time.

Remove `this.generateCode()` as this is not really code that should be ran from a constructor.